# how to recover from error in focus-in-hook

Tags: hooks

I registered a focus-in-hook that generates an error. Now any time I try to execute a command in the minibuffer I get an error and am then unable to execute the `load-file` that would be required to resolve the error. How can I remove this hook or otherwise recover from this situation?

Comment: Have you tried `M-: (remove-hook 'focus-in-hook 'my-func)`?  I created a function that raises an error named `my-func` and was still able to remove the hook in this way (while running `emacs -Q`).  If this doesn't work for you, please provide a minimum working example, or provide a description of the observed behavior vs the expected behavior.

Comment: You can also use `emacs -Q` to visit the file where you do such stuff that breaks things. IOW, edit the file without using your init file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple test seems to suggest that you would still be able to evaluate a lisp expression with `eval-expression` (bound to `M-:`) in this situation.  If so, then try

```
M-: (remove-hook 'focus-in-hook 'my-func)
```

Where `my-func` is the name of the offending function. You can then make the necessary corrections and re-set the hook.